# PHP query to database return in array format

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Let's say I query my database and I get the following result

```
+---+---+-------+
| N | M | score |
+---+---+-------+
| 0 | 2 |    14 |
| 1 | 0 |    22 |
+---+---+-------+
```

After doing `$res = $db->query($query);` Is there anyway to store this information in an array. For example, I've tried doing this

```
      $array = array();    
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {
            array_push($array, array($row[0], $row[1], $row[2]));
      }
```

Because I have this idea that everytime it fetches a row into a numeric array,

`$row[0] = 0 , $row[1] = 2, $row[2] = 14` for the first row and

`$row[0] = 1, $row[1] = 0, $row[2] = 22` for the second row

Please do correct me if I'm wrong because I'm pretty sure I'm wrong :O

EDIT: Reason why I'm asking what $row contains is because I would like to store each row into an array to form a multi dimensional array. For example, `{"E":[[0,1,86],[1,0,96]]}` after `json_encode`. So in order to do that, I need to push each row as an array into another array i.e. push the first row as array `[0,1,86]` into `$array` followed by pushing the second row as array `[1,0,96]`. I doubt I can achieve this by doing an associative array. once again correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM)) {$new[]=$row;}`

Comment: @Dagon care to explain?

Comment: try it see what you get: `print_r($new)`

Comment: @Jeff i specifically did MYSQL_NUM instead of associative because I want to have an array that when encoded into JSON will become {"E": [ [0,2,14], [1,0,22] ]}

Comment: ups, I didn't see that! I deleted my previous comment, cause it was obviosly wrong (not to confuse others).

Comment: @Dagon i also have problems with that because i can't print_r on my php file neither can i view it on chrome dev tools.

Comment: no idea what that means. i'll leave it to fusion3k

Comment: @Dagon Oops. what I meant is that my PHP file is responding to AJAX calls. So it only takes the last echo and 'prints' it out onto the page. I'm relatively new to back-end languages so still asking noob questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is substantially fine (`mysql_fetch_array` is a typo, I think).

The only note: You have to init `$array` before `while` loop, otherwise your `array_push` will fail.

So, your code is working, but solution provided in comment is better, because is shorter and more efficient: with `mysql_fetch_array` you already obtain your desired array, so you have simply to add it to your array, without specifying each key. Also, as per [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), the `$array[] =` syntax is more efficient that `array_push()` if adding only one element to array.

```
$array = array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $res, MYSQL_NUM ) )
{
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

If you prefer, you can obtain same result using [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php):

```
$array = mysqli_fetch_all( $res, MYSQLI_NUM );
```

[Edit:] Obviously, the last two solutions will work only if you want retrieve **all** fields returned by the query.

[Edit 2:] To obtain JSON in your desired format, simply add this line at the end of your code:

```
$json = json_encode( array( 'E' => $array ) );
```

Comment: @CHEWWWWWWWWWW Yes, it works also for your json. See my edited answer to see an example.

Comment: so apparently i did this and it worked, as you said array[] and array_push act the same way but there was once i did it and it didnt work. i probably didnt save the file properly or something.
`'$array = array();

 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $res, MYSQL_NUM ) ) {

    array_push($array, $row );

 }`

Comment: `array_push($array, $row );` is the same as `$array[] = $row;`